# UITableViewCell style goes away after scrolling down

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out why my custom styling for table cells disappears after scrolling down in a table view and them back up. What do I need to do to have the style persist?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : CustomTrendingCell = trendingTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTrendingCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(searchForTrendingTerm(sender:)))
    cell.iconView_search.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.iconView_search.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.iconView_search.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    cell.trendingLabel.text = trendingSearchTerms[indexPath.row]
    cell.elevate(elevation: 4.0) //where my style is being set
    return cell
}

extension UIView {
func elevate(elevation: Double) {
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: elevation)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = abs(CGFloat(elevation))
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
}
}
```

The top 2 items in the screenshot below have been scrolled down and up. The drop shadow styling has been removed. The bottom 2 have the correct styling and have not been scrolled down.
[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apPUh.png)

Comment: The problem is that your shadow is being covered by the lower rows. Don't try to add anything outside the bounds of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution here is to explicitly specify the zPosition of each cell's layer.

You would want to ensure that the upper cell has the higher position so that it's content (shadow) lies over the lower cell.

In your cell for row at function add:

```
cell.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(numberOfRows - indexPath.row)
```